# Excel - how to add decimal dash to the whole column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have list of amounts, which are without decimal dash, but I need to add it before 2 digits from right. Here is the example of data:
[image]

So, basically, I would need to add dash / dot like that:

-1297.25
-5517.92
-4653.97
etc.

I dont know, how to treat it, since the number of digits from left side will change from case to case, therefore I cant use `=REPLACE` function.

Could you advise me, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen shot insinuates that the cells really store Cent values ... if this is the case then make a temporary column where you use a formula =[Cell]/100 to convert to EUR with Cents in decimal place... then copy/paste values back the results and format accordingly.

Comment: Or put 100 in an empty cell, copy, paste special > divide.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a formula, search for a free cell and write a 100 in it. Copy this cell to the clipboard. Select the area you want to edit, right-click on it and select "Insert content...". In the following dialog, simply select Divide and press OK. And that's it.